# How to deal with acks for asynchronous types of tasks

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Right now I have a RabbitMQ queue setup, and I have several workers that are listening for events pushed onto this queue.

The events are essentially string urls (e.g., "https://www.youtube.com"), and it'll be processed through puppeteer.

What I'm wondering is given that puppeteer is asynchronous, is there a way for me return an ack once I've finished all the asynchronous stuff.

Right now, I think my workers listening to the queue are hanging because the ack isn't being fired.

edit -- code below is what I pretty much call within the `consume` part of rabbitmq. Because this is async, it kinda just goes past this operation and just immediately acks.

```
    (async () => {
    const args = {
        evaluatePage: (() => ({
            title: $('title').text(),
        })),
        persistCache: true,
        cache,
        onSuccess: (result => {
            console.log('value for result -- ', result.result.title);
        }),
    };

    // we need to first setup the crawler
    // then we can start sending information to it
    const crawler = await HCCrawler.launch(args);

    crawler.queue(urls);

    await crawler.onIdle();
    await crawler.close();
})();
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: @0.sh sorry just added some code. so in hte `onSuccess` is where I can get the results of the operation. How can I be certain that the onSuccess was called before I run `channel.ack(msg)` ?